# Creating an instance of a class from a function in another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

I'm having trouble figuring out how to **create an instance of an object from another class**.

Below I've given an example, where we have a `MainWindow` class that represents e.g. a web browser. Then, there is another class called `MainWindowTab`.

`MainWindow` is initialized with one tab, called "tab1", but I want to be able to add another tab and call it "tab2" (and then add "tab3", and "tab4" etc), but I'm having problem with naming it as you can see below.

Also, any tips relating to a destructor for the tab objects would be nice if it's not as straightforward as it would seem.

Any help would be great, thanks

**Code**

```python
class MainWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tab = MainWindowTab(0)
        self.tabList = [self.tab]

    def addTab(self, num):
        newName = "tab"+str(len(self.tabList)+1)
        # How to add a new Tab with this name? Below will simply name the new tab as literally 'newName'
        # self.newName = MainWindowTab(10)


class MainWindowTab(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.posn = num
```

Comment: IDK if this works with 100% certainty but I believe you can just add to the add tab function the following: self.tabList.append(MainWindowTab(num))

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What exactly is it that you want to do? It seems you should just create a new instance of `MainWindowTab` and add it to `self.tabList`, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `tab` instance variable a `list`, and then `append` more objects to it

```
class MainWindow(object):
    
    def __init__(self, numberOfTabs):
        self.tab = [MainWindow() for _ in range(numberOfTabs)]
        self.tabList = [self.tab]

    def addTab(self, num):
        newName = "tab"+str(len(self.tabList)+1)
        # How to add a new Tab with this name? Below will simply name the new tab as literally 'newName'
        # self.newName = MainWindowTab(10)
        self.tab.append(MainWindowTab(num))


class MainWindowTab(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.posn = num
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Ah, I see, so the list does contain objects and each of them can have their own attributes. This should work, thanks for the help!

Comment: you're most welcome @WhoDatBoy . Now, please accept my answer if you find it helpful,

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way is to use setattr:

```
def addTab(self, num):
    newName = "tab"+str(len(self.tabList)+1)
    setattr(self, newName, MainWindowTab(10))
```

But as stated in another answer, a better way for sequences data is to use lists.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Nowhere in your code did you ever actually instantiate a new tab though? Did you just forget to add that line before setattr()?

Comment: Yep, i did not get this part of question

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to assign each tab to a new attribute on `self`, just use the list you've already created and access them from there.
Also, you don't need `(object)` in class definitions anymore in Python 3.

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tablist = [MainWindowTab(0)]

    def add_tab(self):
        tab_num = len(self.tablist)
        self.tablist.append(MainWindowTab(tab_num)
```

Now each tab will be accessible as `self.tablist[0]`, `self.tablist[1]`, etc.

For destroying tabs, you'll want to remove them from the main list as well as call whatever destructor method is required on the object itself. Something like:

```
    def kill_tab(self, num):
        """Kill tab number 'num'"""
        try:
            tab = self.tablist.pop(num)
            tab.destroy()
        except IndexError:
            print(f"Tab {num} doesn't exist!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But if each tab is to have its own attributes, don't they each need to be their own objects? Say that the tab objects have their own attributes that may be different for each tab. Does this change things? EDIT: I see that Tab objects were appended to the list and therefore each have their own attributes. I don't know how I missed that on the first read. Thanks for the help!